# Trying to find a way to make java's sound API accept 24 bit audio files and files with more than 2 channels

Tags: audio, javasound, 16-bit

I've been working on a spectrum analyzer this summer and I just bumped into an annoying problem. Playing sounds is a pretty important part of my project and I just learned that the java sound API (javax.sound.sampled package) is incompatible with sound files with more than 2 channels or 16 bits samples.

I've looked online and learned that it is a known issue, but I've had no luck figuring out a way to fix the problem. I guess I could convert the files to 16 bits stereo, but if I can avoid it, I'd love to.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 24 bit works fine for me, Java Sound does support this (I am on macOS 12 with Java 18). I seem to remember older versions of Java didn't support 24 bit on Macs.

Comment: @greg-449 I forgot to mention that this issue is only present on windows. Mac and Linux have no issues with 24 bits audio.